# final casting concept doesn't apply for overloading

Tags: java, casting, overloading

In my casting class, teacher taught us an interesting fact as follows.

```
class Casting {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i = 10;
        byte b = i;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

We got an error

```
java:5: possible loss of precision
```

And then we changed the code as follows

```
class Casting1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int i = 10;
        byte b = i;
        System.out.println(10);
    }
}

10
```

We got the correct output. As for the reason, he told that when we modify a variable `final` the variable is stored in the smallest data type possible. In this case was a `byte`. That's the reason that we were able to cast that without using the cast keyword.

But when we use method overloading like this,

```
class A {
    void m(int i){
        System.out.println("int");
    }
    void m(byte b){
        System.out.println("byte");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1 = new A();
        final int i = 10;
        a1.m(i);
    }
}
```

I get the output `int`. If the final variables are stored in the lowest possible data type, it should be `byte`. So I tried the following code without overloading.

```
class A {
    void m(byte b){
        System.out.println("byte");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1 = new A();
        final int i = 10;
        a1.m(i);
    }
}

java:9: m(byte) in A cannot be applied to (int)
```

What's the reason for this? Is there any point that I have misunderstood?

Comment: in the example with final, you pass the constant 10 to the println.  probably should be b.  you should check if this typo exists in your code, maybe it changes the outcome?

Comment: the first example gives me a compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte.  the second example (with final) passes compilation

Comment: @sharonbn Yeah that's how it's supposed to be. I've mentioned that I get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up memory space of variables and their type.
Calling the method m(...) will first of all check the type of the paramether variable. Here it is an int so it will chose the according overloaded method, no matter the size of the int in memory.

Although I really apreciate you first example that brings the light into one of the characteristics of the final identifier.

Answer (score 2):

This bit isn't quite correct...

*"As for the reason, he told that when we modify a variable final the variable is stored in the smallest data type possible. In this case was a byte."*

It doesn;t store it as a byte, it stores it as an int, BUT it is effectively a constant so when Java compiles the line `byte b = i;` it knows for sure that the value will be 10, which doesn't need casting.

Comment: @Phil, In your answer you mentioned that "Final variables doesn't need casting". can u clarify this statement?

Comment: @Anil: Sure! It's not that final variables don;t need casting per se. It's just that the Java compiler can effectively treat them like constants, because it knows that they'll never change. SO... byte b = i is the same as byte b = 10 which doesn't need casting. Does that help make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any point that I have misunderstood?

Yes. The search for which method to apply depends on the types of the arguments. Unlike the case of assignments, there's no conversion attempt for method arguments (at least, there wasn't before autoboxing was added to the language, which adds another set of arbitrary rules).

Answer (score 0):

If the conversion is part of an assignment, and the value can fit into a `byte`, the compiler performs the conversion automatically for you.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) clearly explains that is a special case that only applies to *assignment* and not to conversions in other contexts.

It's worth mentioning that `byte` is useful only when you program for embedded devices or dealing with files/networks. `byte` and `int` occupy the same space because variables addresses are aligned.